# How do you use images and assets with HTML while using a Flask backend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, flask

I am trying to make a TicTacToe web app with an AI playing as player 2. To do this I coded the game and AI in python, wrote html/javascript front end, and used a flask server. In the html I have img tags and assets such as (these are embedded in the html file in the traditional manner):

```html
<img id="pic" src="assets/images/hil.jpg" class="X">
or
<audio src="assets/audio/smw_coin.wav" id="marioStart" preload="auto"></audio>
```

However, I get errors of this form.

127.0.0.1 - - [11/Feb/2016 23:52:22] "GET /assets/audio/smb_pipe.wav HTTP/1.1" 404 -

127.0.0.1 - - [11/Feb/2016 23:52:22] "GET /assets/js/jquery-1.11.3.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Flask seems to interpret this as a domain name instead of check the assets folder. Does anyone know how to get Flask to interpret the src request as a directory in the flask templates folder?

PS. This is also an issue because it stops me from including JQuery in my html file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flask not finding files in my package's 'static' directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35593283/flask-not-finding-files-in-my-packages-static-directory)  B/c the linked question is asked more generally, this question should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `url_for`.

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/hil.jpg') }}">
```

By default, you'll end up with a URL that looks like `/static/images/hil.jpg` that is served up from your `static` folder. If you'd like to keep the URLs you have, you have to tell Flask to use a different URL path for static assets.

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/assets')
```

This will give you a URL that looks like `/assets/images/hil.jpg' that is served up from your`static` folder. If you've already named the folder assets and you don't want to rename it, you can tell Flask to look for static assets in a different folder, too.

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='assets')
```

This will give you a URL that looks like `/assets/images/hil.jpg` that is served up from your `assets` folder. You don't need to specify both arguments in this case because `static_url_path` uses `static_folder` by default.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot.